# Using jQuery, what is the best way to find the index of a sibling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm

I have a click event on a `td` and it requires finding which `tr` was clicked, whether it was the 1st, 2nd, etc.

How I've started it out is

```
$('.carousel-btn-left').click(function(){
    var ParentRow = $(this).parent();
    var thisRowIndex;
    var AllRows = ParentRow.parent().siblings();    
    for ( var k = 0; k < AllRows.length; ++k )
    {
        if ( AllRows[k] == this )
        {
            thisRowIndex = k;
            break;
        }       
    }
    // ... 
});
```

because I don't know a better way (or even know if that's correct). How should I be doing this?

Comment: `siblings` would get you all sibling TR's, why don't just use `$(this).closest('tr').index()`

Comment: @adeneo I don't know about the `index` function. Thanks for showing me.

Comment: wouldn't have been a very difficult web search `jquery index`

Comment: Should be super-easy when the name of the function is the same as what you wrote in the title.

Comment: FYI, `.siblings()` doesn't include the element that you call it on. So in a loop like yours, it will never find a match. Also, `allRows` is a list of the siblings of the grandparent of `this`, so the elements will never be equal to `this`.